# NA in Optimization function in R (Parametric Portfolio Policy)

Tags: r, optimization, na, quantitative-finance, portfolio

I am trying to maximize an investors utility using the **optim function** in R.
My input to this optimization function are returns and firm characteristics.
The problem is that some of the initial values in my data for ret, m12, mktcap and  btm are **NA**.
I struggle to skip these values in order to find the optimal parameters x[1], x[2] and x[3]. 
Can anyone give advise on how to ignore/work around the NA values in my panel?

So far I have tried setting the NA to 0, however I then get portfolio weights for ALL columns as an output, even for those with the initial value of NA/0. I want to find a way to exclude these firms with NA/0 at every point i of the optimization from the loop, without having to exclude them fully for the whole sample and process.
Thanks so much 
Laura

````
pps = function(x, wb, nt, ret, m12, mktcap, btm, rr){
  wi = wb + nt * (x[1]*m12 + x[2]*mktcap +x[3]*btm)
  wret = rowSums(wi*ret)
  ut = ((1 + wret)^(1-rr))/(1-rr)
  u = -mean(ut)
  return(u)

for(i in 1:189){
  opt = optim(c(0,0,0), pps13, wb = wb, nt = nt, ret= tret[1:(60+i), ], 
              m12 = tmom[1:(60+i), ], mktcap = tsize[1:(60 +i), ], btm = tbtm[1:(60+i), ],
              rr = rr, method = "BFGS")
  res = opt$par 
  w = wb + nt*(res[1]*tmom[i+61, ]+res[2]*tsize[i+61, ] + res[3]*tbtm[i+61, ])
  weightsS[i, ] = w
  parameterSS[i, ] = res
}```
````

Comment: Are you asking how you can skip the values **programmatically** or are you asking what's the best thing to do w.r.t missing data in the context of your optimization problem?

Comment: You need to clean up your data before giving it to the solver.

Comment: Hey, i mean how I can implement it into the function or perhaps the loop. I tried the optimisation with a balanced panel first. No problems! Now that I want to use the whole data set I don’t know how to make the optimisation Of the parameters work, considering only the firms with available data and leaving out the firms with NA values at each point of time.